# How to access GDAL utilities from command line using Rgdal installation?

Tags: gdal, r, windows, rgdal

I have just installed `rgdal` from within R `install.packages("rgdal")`.  I can now successfully do `library(rgdal)` with the following message:

```
Loading required package: sp
rgdal: version: 1.3-9, (SVN revision 794)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20
Path to GDAL shared files: C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.4/library/rgdal/gdal
GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE 
Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016, [PJ_VERSION: 493]
Path to PROJ.4 shared files: C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.4/library/rgdal/proj
Linking to sp version: 1.3-1
```

Based on the startup message, I hoped to find tools like `gdalbuildvrt` in the directory `C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.4/library/rgdal/gdal` but they aren't there, and aren't in the path on the command line.  How do I access these binary tools?

My ultimate goal is to use the `system()` command from my R script to call out to `gdal` directory to do some raster processing.  I don't want to read these big rasters into R because of performance issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gdalUtils` package is a convenient interface to the `GDAL` command utilities. If you install in your R and it can't find the command line utilities then you might need to check the documentation for your platform.

Package description is:

```
> packageDescription("gdalUtils")
Package: gdalUtils
Maintainer: Jonathan Asher Greenberg <gdalUtils@estarcion.net>
License: GPL (>= 2)
Title: Wrappers for the Geospatial Data Abstraction Library (GDAL)
        Utilities
```

`gdalbuildvrt` is wrapped by the package.